# Drupal 8 different layouts in theme

Tags: theming, 8

How do i create theme that has different regions for every node?

For example i want my frontpage to have different regions than some other page that represents content.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager
https://www.drupal.org/project/ds

Answer (score 2):

You don't want different regions for *every* node.

Regions should be as generic and re-usable as possible.

However you don't have to include *all* regions in *all* templates.

Your `page--front.html.twig`could have a different set of regions to `page.html.twig`

Maybe checkout the [Drupal 8 theming guide](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8).

Comment: Yes, it is a little unpractical to have different regions for every node; different regions for different content types is more probable, even though the solution is just not to include all the regions in the template file.